# My code for Project Euler #8 is not working, could somebody help me review it

Tags: c

I did a course on C programming 2 years ago and I was trying to get back into it with the project Euler problems. My code is quite sloppy, sorry for that.

Problem 8 has you calculate the biggest product of 13 consecutive digits in the a very large 1000-digit number.

I wrote some code that uses fgets to read the pasted input and then convert the char ascii values for calculation and output.

My code returns the string of numbers 5576689664895, but this is apparently wrong. I have already tried to prevent overflow errors by using long long ints for all the numbers which could possibly get large.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int highest=0;
long long int highestproduct=0;
char string[1050]={};
long long int product(int i);

int main(){

    fgets(string,1050,stdin);
    for(int i=0; i<1050;i++){
        if((int)string[i+12]==10){
            i=1050;
        }
        else if(product(i)>highestproduct){
            highestproduct=product(i);
            highest=i;
        };
    }
    for(int z=0; z<13; z++){
        printf("%d", string[highest+z]-48);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

long long int product (int i){
    long long int interm=1;
    int numbers=0;
    for(int n=0; n<13; n++){
        numbers=(int)string[i+n];
        numbers=numbers-48;
        interm=interm * numbers;
    }
    return interm;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't read the problem description carefully. The string that you are printing is not what the problem is asking for. Your code looks like it finds the solution to the problem but doesn't print it.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void main(){
    int max=882;
    int num=0;
    int strnum[1000],N;
    char ch[100];
    FILE *fp=fopen("problem8.txt","r");
    while(fgets(ch,100,fp)){
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
            strnum[num+i]=ch[i]-'0';
        num+=50;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    for(int i=0;i<995;i++){
        N=strnum[i]*strnum[i+1]*strnum[i+2]*strnum[i+3]*strnum[i+4];
        if(max<N)
            max=N;
    }
    printf("%d\n",max);
}
```

[from here](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_9f26be1d01012kdh.html)